# SFDX: Deploy Source to Org failed to run - File or folder not found

Tags: salesforcedx, deployment

[image]

Ok, I have my VScode setup to deploy to my org on save - I've done this TONS of other times, I have it setup the same way as always. I'm hooked up to an org, I can retrieve source from org, I can *right click* the files on the left hand explorer and use "SFDX: Deploy Source to Org" and it works just fine. BUT, when I hit save I get the error that shows in the screenshot: %s: File or folder not found -- it's driving me crazy. It totally kills my workflow to have to manually right click and deploy as opposed to on save.

Deploying on save was working when I first setup my project, then I installed GIT on my local machine, initialized a local repository, THEN my deploy on save stopped working.

I tried uninstalling my plugins, VScode itself, and GIT *multiple* times (I've spent the last 4 hours on this). I've made sure to totally wipe out all of VScode when doing it as well, but no luck.

Is there anywhere I can see the terminal command that happens when I hit save, to make sure it's firing properly?

Comment: seems this was [fixed](https://github.com/forcedotcom/salesforcedx-vscode/issues/3655)